# What is the system-wide location for init.el?

Tags: init-file, system-environment

Is there a way to have a common `init.el` for several system users?
/etc/emacs.d/init.el for example?

Comment: How about everyone's `.emacs` file having a one-liner?:  `(load "/path/to/master/init.el" nil t t nil)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in chapter [49.4 The Emacs Initialization File](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html#Init-File) of the Emacs manual (which is also included as part of Emacs, use `C-h i` to open the info browser which will show you this and many other manuals already on your computer). In short, Emacs loads both `site-lisp.el` and `defaults.el` in addition to your own startup file, and these two files may be located anywhere in the `load-path`. Exactly what directories end up in your `load-path` may vary across operating systems and distributions, but in most Linux distributions it will include a directory like `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp`.